# How long does Outlook 2016 cache add-in images?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We've an Outlook web add-in deployed to various sets of users. The server that serves the add-in files, including icons, sets Cache-Control headers on responses with an expiry of 7 days. We generally see that clients such as browsers OWA or Outlook for Mac will request these icons initially and then use the cache when the icons are next required, respecting the cache header.

However with the Windows Outlook 2016 client we're seeing repeat requests for the add-in icons in the ribbon within 24 hours of them originally being delivered to the client.

Does Outlook 2016 have a built in cache expiry time / does it ignore caching rules for add-in icons?

- Specifically referring to the add-in ribbon icons here as it seems to be the act of a user starting Outlook for the day is causing the icon request to be made.

Note we see this across a range of Outlook 2016 versions from users so can't narrow it to a specific version but safe to assume it's widespread based on the number of requests we're seeing from distinct groups.

Comment: Do you get this working correctly in MS Edge?

Comment: The expected behavior, as posted below, is that Outlook 2016 should not request for icons that are already cached. This means that the requests you are seeing are probably for icons that failed to download or failed while attempting to cache them locally. Are you able to get a Fiddler trace to help us better understand what is going on? Or are you only seeing this behavior based on server logs and so you don't have an in-house client exhibiting this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to find out which browser engine is used for hosting the web add-in in Outlook. Office Add-ins are web applications that are displayed using `iFrames` when running in Office on the web and using embedded browser controls in Office for desktop and mobile clients. Add-ins also need a JavaScript engine to run the JavaScript. Both the embedded browser and the engine are supplied by a browser installed on the user's computer.

Which browser is used depends on:

- The computer's operating system.
- Whether the add-in is running in Office on the web, Microsoft 365, or non-subscription Office 2013 or later.

See [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) for more information.

Comment: It'll be IE 11 as this is specifically happening with the Outlook 2016 client. "non-subscription Office 2013 or later" from the browsers link.

Answer (score 0):

The product team indicates that Outlook actually doesn't respect Cache Headers at all for ribbon icons, but Cache Headers can affect the ability to download Ribbon Icons. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#hosting-requirements (though that link only mentions no-cache options) You may try removing cache-control headers completely, to see if it affects the issue?

Office/Outlook should not be requesting new icons if it already has them, icons are cached locally in this folder:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\Resources
```

Are your icons there?

Comment: This is affecting a spread of external users so can't examine that folder but on a single Office 2016 install yes the icons are present after client loads.

I'm confused by that link as it says "All image URIs, such as those used for add-in commands, must support caching.". But then immediately says that "The server hosting the image should not return a Cache-Control header specifying no-cache, no-store, or similar options in the HTTP response.". So what's the expected way for to implement caching here if not via those headers?